# Looping inifinito

Tags: python, lista, loop, for

Estou transcrevendo de Java para Python um código para resolver um Sudoku 4/4.

Quando testo o código ele não executa e fica rodando infinitamente, aparentemente em um dos métodos da classe Artista. Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

```
import random

class Artista:

    __caracteristicas = list(range(0,4))

    def __init__(self):
        self.gerar_caracteristicas_artista()

    def gerar_caracteristicas_artista(self):
        aux = random.randrange(0,4) + 1
        for i, v in enumerate(self.__caracteristicas):
            while self.__verifica_repeticao(aux):
                aux = random.randrange(0,4) + 1
            self.__caracteristicas[i] = aux

    def __verifica_repeticao(self,valor):
        for i, v in enumerate(self.__caracteristicas):
            if valor == v:
                return True
        return False

    def imprime_caracteristicas(self):
        print(self.__caracteristicas)

    def get_caracteristicas(self):
        return self.__caracteristicas from sudoku import Artista class Grupo:
    __artistas = list(range(0,4))

    def __init__(self):
        artista1 = Artista.Artista()
        artista2 = Artista.Artista()
        artista3 = Artista.Artista()
        artista4 = Artista.Artista()
        self.__artistas.clear()
        self.__artistas = [artista1,artista2,artista3,artista4]

    def imprime_artistas(self):
        for i in self.__artistas:
            self.__artistas[i].imprime_caracteristicas()
            print('\n') from sudoku import Grupo

class Sudoku:
    grupo= Grupo.Grupo()
    grupo.imprime_artistas()
```

Comment: tem algumas coisas em seu codigo que ñ reconheço como funciona
'''def get_caracteristicas(self):
        return self.__caracteristicas from sudoku import Artista class Grupo:
    __artistas = list(range(0,4))''' 
como essa parte funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Não mexo muito com Python, mas encontrei algumas coisas meio que fora de lugar nesse código. Como você está transcrevendo de Java, está tentando fazer algumas coisas que são permitidas em Java, mas que não funcionam em Python.

Em Python, se você definir um método, e mais a frente definir novamente esse mesmo método, a sua definição anterior será 'sobrescrita', Python interpretará apenas a última definição do método.

No seu código, ao definir `__init__(self)` uma segunda vez, você apagou a primeira definição,
logo, o comando `self.gerar_caracteristicas_artista()` não será executado.
Para resolver isto, basta definir uma única vez o método, com tudo o necessário dentro.

Em python, para criar uma instância de um classe, não é necessário fazer Artista.Artista(), basta apenas Artista() (Embora para mim não faça sentido você instanciar uma classe dentro da criação da própria classe, pelo que entendo isso criaria algo recursivo, criando uma instância dentro de outra e dentro de outra, e assim sucessivamente, acredito que seja nesta parte que esteja dando loop).

No seu método `get_caracteristicas(self)`, assim como no `imprime_artistas(self)`, acredito que seja outra coisa que funciona em Java, mas que não é bem assim em Python. Se você quer importar uma classe de algum módulo, defina isso no início do código, assim como fez com random.

Dito isto, acho que esses são os principais erros nesse código (embora eu ainda esteja tentando entender a lógica do método `gerar_caracteristicas_artista(self)`, para mim, ou ele entra em loop, ou sempre vai produzir a mesma sequência, mas enfim).

Melhor conhecer um pouco mais da sintaxe de Python antes de transcrever, se não muitos erros ainda vão aparecer nesse código.
Existem muitas boas referências, embora a maioria em inglês. Procurando um pouco no youtube, irá encontrar diversos tutoriais para orientação a objeto.